# Print option in invoice view

Tags: customer, invoice, print, account-dashboard

I am looking for a **print option** in **invoice view page** of **customer account dashboard**.

> We would like for our customers to be able to not only view their
>   invoices, but print them as well.

So when a **customer** goes into their **account dashboard** and clicks on a **available invoice**, we want there to be an option to print the invoice for their records.

Over by the return we would like a link that says Print to print the below invoice.

[image]